# Using named queries

Tags: grails

I have a named query in a domain class:

```
class Store {
    static namedQueries {
        openOnWeekends {
            // some conditions here...
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can do `Store.openOnWeekends.list()`, but I want to do something like this:

```
def pickupWeekendStores = Order.get(params.id).books.store.openOnWeekends
```

Is there a way to use named queries like that? Any suggestions on how to get the stores open on weekends?

Edit:

```
Order hasMany Book, Book hasMany Store
```

Comment: Could you expand with your relevant domain classes? There are multiple answers, depending on how you modeled your relationships.

Comment: just edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Named queries support additional criteria at invocation, so you could try:

```
Store.openOnWeekends {
    books {
        'in'('id', Order.get(params.id).books.collect { it.id })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does doing something like:

```
Set<Store> pickupWeekendStores = Order.get(params.id).books*.store.collect { it.openOnWeekends.list() }
```

work?